# API to make payment

Tags: python, payment, stripe-payments, braintree

I am developing an API, and I was wondering if there is anything again a user entering in their credit card information to make a payment via an API. Something like:

```
requests.POST(url, data = {
    api_key: 'asdf',
    api_secret: 'asdf'
    cc_number: '1234123412341234',
    cc_cvc: '1234',
    cc_exp: '2014-10-01'
}
```

Provided that I don't save the credit card information, is it OK to allow this in an API call? The actual payment would be handled by Braintree or Stripe, but I do need to authenticate the user and save the update to my database.

Comment: The moment someone's CC details are anywhere close piece of software you are running, you are asking for trouble.

Comment: @remus - OP says that they do NOT want to store the cardholder data - at least OP already knows that.

Comment: @mhawke correct, but even having them in that form allows for the data to be hijacked and stolen with a page infection. While when you do not do that, even infected page will not be able to hi-jack credit card details so easily.

Comment: With services like the ones you mention in your question (I work at Braintree), you send the CC info to the processor directly from the form, and they return a token you can then save & use without having to handle credit card info. You don't send the CC info to your own site. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+python has examples.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot against it.  You're going to want to adhere to [PCI guidelines](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/) on this one, notably...

> The Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard (PCI DSS) is a set of requirements designed to ensure that ALL companies that **process**, **store** or **transmit** credit card information maintain a secure environment. Essentially any merchant that has a Merchant ID (MID).

Doing anything with a credit card number on the wire is only advisable if:

- You encrypt the line it's being transmitted on
- You encrypt the actual credit card information in whatever data store you use
- You segregate the credit card information from anything else
- You disallow direct access to that credit card information to "mere mortals" (that is, you don't just allow developers direct access to credit card information
- You ensure that your third party API is PCI compliant (***very*** important)

Playing with credit cards is like playing with uranium.  You can reap great benefits from it, but one spill and the mess will take years to clean up.  Make it a big *enough* spill and your career can become radioactive.

Answer (score 0):

At a bare minimum you need to use SSL.

However, there is a little thing called [PCI-DSS](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/index.php) which covers this sort of thing, and a lot more besides.

Basically though, collecting cardholder data outside of a PCI compliant system (which Braintree, Stripe and most other payment gateways are), creates onerous PCI compliance obligations for yourself or your merchants, and you should seek to avoid it if possible.

You could look at using the tokenisation services offered by your proposed payment gateways, if that can be made to fit into your payment workflow.